# No .vcd file found error, but I have used the $dump code

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, test-bench, iverilog, edaplayground

I have been trying to open EPWave at EDA playground, and it always returns the error:

> No *.vcd file found. EPWave will not open. Did you use
> '$dumpfile("dump.vcd"); $dumpvars;'?

I have added those two at the beginning of the `initial`, and yet it's not working (also the `$finish` of course)

This is the project: https://www.edaplayground.com/x/SzkF

I have tried adding time before and after the finish and beginning, naming the dumpfile in another way looking some similar code, but none of that has worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`iverilog` does not always give very useful error messages.  Switch to another simulator on EDA Playground.  For example, with the Cadence simulator, we get this error message:

```
  reg[0] b_reg;
       |
xmvlog: *E,SVNPSN (design.sv,132|7): The value in the single-bound form of a range must be positive.
  reg[0] b_reg;
       |
xmvlog: *E,SVPKSN (design.sv,132|7): The single-bound form of a range is only allowed for array (i.e., unpacked) dimensions.
```

I can get rid of the compile error when I change:

```
  reg[0] b_reg;
```

to:

```
  reg b_reg;
```

Switching back to `iverilog`, I no longer see the original VCD error message.